# Install PHP 5.1.2, Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) error

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to install php 5.1.2 on a CentOS 6 server (for grandfathering in old websites).

I downloaded an RPM file ( php-5.1.2-5.x86_64.rpm ), but when I use:

`yum install php-5.1.2-5.x86_64.rpm`

I get the following error:

> Error: Package: php-5.1.2-5.x86_64 (/php-5.1.2-5.x86_64)
>              Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)

I have tried several things including the following:

`ln -s /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3` (To make it symlink to the newer version)

Downloaded curl-7.15.5-2.1.el5_3.5.x86_64.rpm and took the libcurl.so.3 out of the rpm and placed it in /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3 with the same permissions as libcurl.so.4.

Nothing has worked.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to install libcurl.x86_64 and libcurl-devel.x86_64?

Comment: I already had libcurl.x86_64 installed, I installed libcurl-devel.x86_64 after reading your question.  It had no effect though :(

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it'll help, but I just had the exact same issue and I found that I accidentally installed a repo for CentOS 5, instead of 6. You might want to check your repos

Comment: I found I had a similar issue with my repos. Fixed, ran update then re-ran the install and the error did not recur. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just symlink to a different library version, the versioning is there specifically because different versions are incompatible.

You need to find or build the package for CentOS 6 so that it uses the appropriate libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This issue will happen with other package installs not just php 5.1.2.

In my case I investigated Marc DiBlasi's solution and brought the repos on the problem machine in alignment with the other servers and run update.

When issues like this occur it would be a small thing to check the quality of your repo configuration.